# Paypal REST Oauth giving redirect error

Tags: php, paypal, oauth, oauth-2.0

Paypal is giving me this error

```
Relying Party Validation error: redirect_uri provided in the request does not match with the registered redirect_uri. Please check the request.
```

When trying to get an oAuth login box to show up. I have copy and pasted the redirect_uri from paypal into my code.

This is the URL i'm directing the user to

```
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize?client_id=<MYCLIENTID>&response_type=code&scope=email&redirect_uri=<MYREDIRECTURL>
```

Note that  is copy and pasted from App return URL (live) on `https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/editapp`

Any idea how to get past this error?

Comment: Note that i've tried url-encoding and not url-encoding the URI

Comment: Did you fix this prolem? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I contacted paypal and they had to "enable some setting" on their end. And they said yes it was only something they could do on their end.